# Show that $V(\bigcup_{i \in I} E_{i})=\bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_{i})$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a part of a problem in Atiyah's Introduction to Commutative Algebra introducing the Zariski Topology.

Here we are given that $(E_{i})_{i \in I}$ is a family of subsets of a unital commutative ring $A$. We take $V(E)$ for any subset $E$ of $A$ to be the set of all prime ideals containing $E$.

The problems asks us to show $V(\bigcup_{i \in I} E_{i})=\bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_{i})$.

My original argument was likely false and made no use of the fact that we are working with prime ideals. My question is essentially where in this proof do we make use of the fact that we are working with prime ideals. I'm rather confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim**: If $(E_i)_{i \in I}$ is any family of subsets of $A$, then $$V\bigg( \bigcup_{i \in I} E_i \bigg) = \bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_i).$$

To answer your question: We use prime ideals when showing each side is contained in the other. We pick an arbitrary prime ideal, $\mathfrak p$ in one and show it's contained in the other one. Notice that the primality of the ideals doesn't come into play in the proof.

**Proof**: Let $(E_i)_{i \in I}$ be any family of subsets of $A$.

Let $\mathfrak p \in V\bigg( \bigcup_{i \in I} E_i \bigg)$, then $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal containing $\bigcup_{i \in I} E_i$. For each $i \in I$, $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal containing $E_i$. Hence $\mathfrak p \in V(E_i)$, therefore, $\mathfrak p \in \bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_i)$.

Let $\mathfrak p \in \bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_i)$, then $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal containing $E_i$ for each $i \in I$. Hence $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal containing $\bigcup_{i \in I} E_i$, therefore, $\mathfrak p \in V\bigg( \bigcup_{i \in I} E_i \bigg)$.

Conclude that $V\bigg( \bigcup_{i \in I} E_i \bigg) = \bigcap_{i \in I} V(E_i).$

Comment: Ok, great, I worried that something was wrong with that argument.